# Extract a unique distinct list sorted alphabetically and ignore blanks from a range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to solve the requirement mentioned in the above subject line. To do that, I have taken the following formula from the link mentioned below

```
=INDEX($B$3:$B$7, SMALL(IF(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($D$2:D2, $B$3:$B$7)+ISBLANK($B$3:$B$7)=0, COUNTIF($B$3:$B$7, "<"&$B$3:$B$7)+1, ""), 1)=IF(ISBLANK($B$3:$B$7), "", COUNTIF($B$3:$B$7, "<"&$B$3:$B$7)+1), ROW($B$3:$B$7)-MIN(ROW($B$3:$B$7))+1), 1), MATCH(MIN(IF(COUNTIF($D$2:D2, $B$3:$B$7)+ISBLANK($B$3:$B$7)>0, "", COUNTIF($B$3:$B$7, "<"&$B$3:$B$7)+1)), INDEX(IF(ISBLANK($B$3:$B$7), "", COUNTIF($B$3:$B$7, "<"&$B$3:$B$7)+1), SMALL(IF(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF($D$2:D2, $B$3:$B$7)+ISBLANK($B$3:$B$7)=0, COUNTIF($B$3:$B$7, "<"&$B$3:$B$7)+1, ""), 1)=IF(ISBLANK($B$3:$B$7), "", COUNTIF($B$3:$B$7, "<"&$B$3:$B$7)+1), ROW($B$3:$B$7)-MIN(ROW($B$3:$B$7))+1), 1), , 1), 0), 1)
```

link-> https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/09/16/extract-a-unique-distinct-list-sorted-alphabetically-removing-blanks-from-a-range-in-excel/

This formula is working fine in Google sheets as depicted in the screen shot below

[image]

[image]

But failing (ie not uniquely finding the values) in my laptop excel version - MS Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.4738.1000) 32-bit

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. In Excel, an easy way to get a list of unique values based on a list of repeated values would be: A) Use a Pivot Table (this would preserve your original data) B) Or Remove Duplicates (this would modify your original data)

Comment: That is an array formula and must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.